# The ajax call in the Jq function of a bootstrap toggle does not get called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I am trying to call a function that when clicked goes to the controller (I am working on MVC project) but for some unknown reason the function does not get called.  I have used this before with other buttons and grid selections and it used to work properly, can any one help with this question?

I have a bootstrap toggle button that is as follows:

```
<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox"  data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled ">
```

The function is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggle-event').change(function() {

        $('#console-event').html('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'))

            var nodeURL = document.getElementById("IDHolder").innerHTML;
            var nodeConfig = nodeURL + ".CONFIG";
            var nodeAdd = nodeURL + ".CONFIG.Enable";
            var ListNodedetS = [];
            var ListNodedetI = [];
            var Listmet = [nodeConfig, nodeAdd];
            var params = {

                ListNodeDetailsString: ListNodedetS,

                ListNodeDetailsInt: ListNodedetI,

                ListMethod: Listmet
            };

        var temp = {
            url: "/Configuration/CallMethod",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            success: function (params) {
                window.location.replace(params.redirect);
            }
        };
    })
})
```

Controller part:

```
public bool CallMethod(List<string> ListNodeDetailsString, List<string> ListNodeDetailsInt, List<string> ListMethod)
    {


        var AddMethod = RxMUaClient.CallMethod(ListNodeDetailsString,ListNodeDetailsInt, ListMethod, "127.0.0.1:48030");
        return AddMethod;
    }
```

The ajax call was used before on different buttons and it worked normally, but now since it is called as an action of checking the bootstrap toggle it does not work.

The other jq that works:

```
$('#AddActivity').click(function () {

    var nodeURL = document.getElementById("IDHolder").innerHTML;
    var nodeName = $("#ActivityName").val();
    var nodeType = $("#ActivityType").data("kendoComboBox").value();
    var nodeConfig = nodeURL + ".CONFIG";
    var nodeAdd = nodeURL + ".CONFIG.AddActivity";

    var ListNodedetS = [nodeName];
    var ListNodedetI = [nodeType];
    var Listmet = [nodeConfig, nodeAdd];
    var params = {

        ListNodeDetailsString: ListNodedetS,

        ListNodeDetailsInt: ListNodedetI,          

        ListMethod: Listmet
    };

    var temp = {
        url: "/Configuration/CallMethod",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        success: function (params) {
            window.location.replace(params.redirect);
        }
    };
```

Comment: I suspect your Synchronous warning is red-herring and nothing to do with your code - test this by removing your js code temporarily and trying again.

Comment: Yes, the warning is nothing to do with the js code.

Comment: So can you determine where the problem lies?  A cursory look at the event handler wire-up looks fine, but there's quite a bit of flack that is likely to be not relevant.  Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The problem is calling the ajax within the toggle button. When i debug the code the Callmethod in the controller is not called and the data is not passed, while before it used to work on other buttons! I hope the editing is useful.

Comment: Ok - so the jquery function is getting hit?   But it's not getting to your `CallMethod`?  I recommend you update the title of the question in the first instance.  Next, where is `CallMethod` defined?  seems strange that it returns a `boolean`, but your `params` return value is expecting at least a 'redirect' property on the return type.  Next, does `CallMethod` have `[HttpGet]` or similar attributes?

Comment: Then, just before the `var temp = `, do a console output of params, ie: `console.dir(JSON.stringify(params))` to check it's what you expect.

Comment: Yes the params are displayed. And so the jq function got hit but the Callmethod is not reached. The CallMethod is defined in a controller called Configuration. No it does not have [HttpGet]

Comment: Then what's the method signature of the ones that work?  I would expect it to be something like `public JsonResult CallMethod(`.

Comment: The controller method is working fine but the call can not reach it. I added another call which works properly to the question.

Comment: You might like to refactor the actual call to a separate method, then you be repeating code and can rule any potential issue out there.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using anything to do with bootstrap here, your input has an `id` and you're wiring it up via jquery (`$('#toggle-event').change(`) - like the Synchronous warning, you might like to eliminate that by reducing the input to simple `<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox"/>`.  If that works, then it *is* something to do with bootstrap.   Back to the *minimal* part of the mcve faq.